# Create the GA Ecommerce "addItem" code using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to populate the GA e-commerce code using jQuery, or JS. I don't have access to the code, so I am unable to populate them from the actual page - which is a pain in the backside, i know!

I have so far been able to get the order number and order total. To get each product in the basket I have been trying to get each row `order-item` and then grab the data to populate an instance of `ecommerce:addItem` per item. I then need to append it to the page so i have a `ga('ecommerce:addItem', { });` per item in the order.

I was wondering if anyone else has a better idea to do this. Here is my code so far, any improvements would be much appreciated. I think a better option maybe to create the `ga('ecommerce:addItem', { });` and then return them to the page, but i am not sure how to do this.

```
<script>
    var order_id = document.getElementsByClassName('order_id')[0].innerText
    var order_total = document.getElementsByClassName('order_total')[0].innerText

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': order_id,
      'affiliation': 'Test Store',
      'revenue': order_total,
      'currency': 'GBP'
    });

    $('.order_item').each(function(){
      ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': order_id,
        'name': $(this).find('.product-name')[0].innerText,
        'sku': $(this).find('.product-sku')[0].innerText,
        'price': $(this).find('.item_price')[0].innerText,
        'quantity': $(this).find('.iitem_qty')[0].innerText
      });

      ga('ecommerce:send');
    });


    ga('ecommerce:clear');
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the send function into the each loop worked.

The reason it didn't work was due to the transaction items not being sent to GA

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont need to clear after send because "Once complete, the shopping cart is cleared and ready to send data for a new transaction. If a previous ecommerce:send command was issued, only new transaction and item data will be sent."
See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#sendingData